# Подтверждение личности в Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

Я зарегистрировался как разработчик в Google Play для публикации приложения, заплатил 25$, отправил скан водительского удостоверения. Google ответил, что не может удостоверить мою личность. Тогда я сделал скан паспорта и отправил еще раз. Google сказал, что всё равно не может удостоверить мою личность, у меня кончились попытки и больше я ничего не смогу сделать.

Тогда я создал еще один почтовый ящик, новый аккаунт, повторил попытку и Google отпинал меня сразу с первой попытки и тщательным высококачественным сканом паспорта. Более того, вот уже месяц, а заплаченные мной 25$ мне так и не вернули. До этого момента моя активность в Google была нулевая.
Вопрос, какие еще тонкости идентификации могут быть и есть ли смысл обратиться напрямую в офис Google в Москве?

Comment: Пишите в поддержку, мы вам деньги точно не вернём :)

Comment: Я не сказал. Конечно решал возврат через техподдержку.

Comment: Интересная история. А в чем собственно состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: Основной вопрос, сталкивался ли кто-то ещё с такой проблемой?

Comment: Постарайтесь пожалуйста конкретизировать ваш вопрос. "Какие еще тонкости .. могут быть и есть ли смысл обратиться напрямую в офис" не является чем-то, на что можно дать объективный ответ.

Comment: "сталкивался ли кто-то ещё с такой проблемой?" - это бесполезный вопрос. Допустим Петров Имярек сталкивался и А.Н.Оним.. и что с того?

Comment: Я ищу поддержку сообщества, если таковая возможна, поэтому не вижу проблемы, что вопрос может быть размытым. Если кому-то есть что ответить, он ответит.

Comment: StackOverflow работает немного не так ..